# can't create a jobs user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm stuck on this page even after linking stackoverflow and github accounts.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message when you hit the "Get Started" button?

Comment: I was able to repro this, investigating.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for reporting this!

Due to some mistakes on our side this create page was having some hidden errors (technically it was failing because you hadn't yet given us information that we hadn't asked you to give us) which is awful. A fix is going out right now and we'll definitely add better reporting/tests for this flow ASAP.